# Newline in telegram inline keyboard for python

Tags: python-3.x, text, python-telegram-bot

my button text is too long to fit in one line of my inline keyboard for the python telegram bot. "\n" wont do.

Code info: /key is the only command it understands. It reads the API token from the file token.txt in the code directory.

Here is my code:

```
from pprint import pprint
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram.ext import InlineQueryHandler
from telegram.ext import CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent
import logging
import time, threading, pickle

file = open("token.txt", "r")
TOKEN = file.read()

updater = Updater(TOKEN)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',level=logging.INFO)

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def start(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

def key_menu(bot, update):

    text = "Some really long text I\n want on two rows :D"
    callback = "nothing"

    keyboard = []
    keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(text, callback_data = callback)])

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Some text', reply_markup=reply_markup)    

key_menu_handler = CommandHandler('key', key_menu, pass_args=False)
dispatcher.add_handler(key_menu_handler)


updater.start_polling()
```

[image]

The second message is with the "\n" inserted. The first one is just text. Another option would be for everyone to get a bigger phone :D

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use `\n` in buttons and the max width is fixed for every devices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is there any workaround? Because especially it being different for every device is quite problematic...

Comment: make the text shorter! lol

Comment: you dont say... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible for `InlineKeyboardButton`, but possible for `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` (it is bigger and support resize option) if it works for you.

But preferred way is to show that really long text in message and for button - use really short version for inline buttons.

**Example:**

```py
buttons = [
    ['Some really long text I \n'
     'want on two rows :D'],
    ['Some really long text I \n'
     'want on two rows :D']
]
keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons, resize_keyboard=True)

update.message.reply_text('Some message', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If you could show a screenshot and a small code sample I will accept the answer :)

Comment: @JulianWgs added example and screenshot.

Comment: Thank you! Haven‘t checked if it works, since Ive moved on from Telegram bots :D